# wifi works from live DVD but firmware does not load from fully updated kubuntu xenial

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, firmware

Hi:  This is an old HP 6710b laptop on which wifi worked until a multi-package upgrade via a slightly flaky wifi link on 2017 June 5. It has a fully updated kubuntu xenial installation.

On another "identical" laptop wifi still works.  That was last upgraded in March 2017 and I would like to feel able to bring it up-to-date

The basic problem seems to be that the iwl3945 firmware is not being loaded.  It is present in `/lib/firmware` and all the md5 sums are identical. Firmware required by a Netgear dongle is not loaded either.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [103c:135c]
        Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
        Kernel modules: iwl3945, wl
18:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1693] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 6710b [103c:30c0]
        Kernel driver in use: tg3

$ dmesg | grep firmware
[    3.348625] tg3 0000:18:00.0: VPD access failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update
```

There are more details here, although the title bug there is not the one I am asking about  [iwl3945 crashes randomly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1627828/comments/19)

I mentioned there that wifi worked with a SL7 live disk, but that seemed unlikely to lead anywhere.  After more experiments I tried again with today's live kubuntu build, and again wifi works - so it isn't a problem with the distributed packages but with my configuratiion.  Can I transfer that, or find out what is wrong with it, without a complete reinstall ?

Thanks.

The warning about the tg3 driver is long-standing and appears on the working laptop too.  But that has "iwl3945  loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9" as well.

There was nothing to purge.  Rebooted.  Nothing has changed.

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   32.166948] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[   32.166950] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[   32.166950] iwl3945: hw_scan is disabled
[   32.167017] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   32.222511] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23 802.11a channels
[   32.222514] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
[   32.379975] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[   35.110144] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0 wlp16s0: renamed from wlan0

$ iwconfig
ens1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp16s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
       logical name: wlp16s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1c:bf:63:04:9f
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=4.13.0-32-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:25 memory:e4100000-e4100fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:18:00.0
       logical name: ens1
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1a:4b:83:3d:4f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=sb v2.09 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:27 memory:e4000000-e400ffff

$ sudo iwlist scan
wlp16s0   Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

ens1      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Thanks. I posted `dmesg | grep iwl`  and `dmesg | grep firmware` earlier.  There were no references to the firmware file.  `modinfo` shows h/w scan disabled, which I may have done earlier, and might not apply in Live mode.  The connection in Live mode, and with the other laptop, are all with the same router, so its settings oughtn't to be a problem.

I'm afraid I haven't used your input screen before and am finding it difficult to see the history, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Please see my edit in a few moments.

Answer (score 2):

The reference to firmware in your `dmesg` relates to the driver tg3 which is an ethernet driver. It is unrelated to wireless.

I suggest that you remove the incorrect and possibly competing driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot. Is the wireless working? If not, post:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
iwconfig
```

**EDIT**: We still see no evidence that it is a firmware problem; in fact, when an interface is created, in your case wlp16s0, that strongly suggests that the correct firmware *did* load. Check:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Doesn’t firmware=15.32.2.9 or some such appear?

In `dmesg`, if the firmware failed to be found and loaded, it would be very evident; something like this:

```
iwl3945 0000:05:00.0: iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode firmware file req failed: -2
```

Does the interface scan or does it throw an error?

```
Sudo iwlist scan
```

Please note here:

```
Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23 802.11a channels
```

This device was designed and built prior to the advent of 802.11N. That means that if your wireless router or access point is locked to 802.11N, your iwl3945 device won’t even see it. Please make sure that the router is set to 802.11A, B and G and a fixed channel; either channel 1, 6 or 11.

When you click the Network Manager icon, please be certain that Enable Networking and Enable Wireless are selected. If you make any changes, restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Make all tests with the ethernet detached as NM will default to ethernet if it’s available as it is often faster and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Wifi is now working again on this laptop - at least at a range of about 2 meters from the router.  It does also show other potential connection points further away.

After I discovered that the Live DVD allowed connection from box A I decided to update its twin, B, and have had them side-by-side.  Synaptic showed that B had *no* packages found by a search for broadcom, and I removed them all from A.  They would almost certainly have been installed during earlier investigations.  Mostly they were B43-related.  I don't know what caused the original post-upgrade failure.

The responses to "sudo lshw -C network" then started to look similar and "rfkill list" showed that I needed "rfkill unblock 0"  and "rfkill unblock 2"

The usual incomprehensible NM and security-related difficulties followed in getting a usable connection, but it's working and has survived reboots.

"dmesg | grep iwl33945" does now show a firmware load and has a new warning about possible misbehaviour if power management is enabled - related to ref [1]

Thanks for the help.